# Semantics to express gradle dependencies

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, gradle-dependencies

I see that I can specify gradle dependencies like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.8.1'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.8.1'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.1'
}
```

but also like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile(
        'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.8.1',
        'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.8.1',
        'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.1'
    )
}
```

This means that the `compile` configuration applies to a single element but also to a list of elements. Where do I find more details about the `compile` semantics? I'm referring also to details like the `exclude module` clause:

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.simpleframework:simple-xml:2.7.1') {
        exclude module: 'stax'
        exclude module: 'stax-api'
        exclude module: 'xpp3'
    }
}
```

I've seen [this](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Dependencies-on-binary-packages) page, but it doesn't contain this kind of details. Does Android Studio offer some kind of help to learn Gradle semantics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the [DependencyHandler DSL documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.dsl.DependencyHandler.html).

You can access Gradle API documentation from Android Studio like javadocs for Android framework APIs eg. using Quick Documentation shortcut (in default keymap `Ctrl+Q` or `F1` on OS X).

You have to use Gradle `all` distribution. Eg. if you are using gradle wrapper it can be set in `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` like that: 
`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip`